# What is the use of the bank?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

At every inn, there's a bank where you can throw in gold, in chunks of 1000, to get later.

That gold seems to just sit there and do nothing. There's no interest (where you would put in 1000, pull back 1050 later), there's no mechanic where you would lose money, for instance on death.

So it does feel like putting money in the bank has basically no use. So why is it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you die and choose to return to the last point you saved at or last place visited (but not last autosave), it doesn't reload your last save; rather, you keep any progress intact, except you lose half your money. Money in the bank is exempt from this.

This has, I believe, been the purpose of banks since the very first Dragon Quest, and even some other games such as Pokémon Mystery Dungeon.

Comment: If I remember right, the warning when loading last save is 'You will lose any experience and gold you've earned since' but no word on it making you also lose half your current money.

Comment: @Fredy31 That appears to be the last autosave option, not the last save point option.

Comment: Ill try to pay attention next time I game over. But maybe the banks are just a reminder of what was before. DQ11 is my first one, but it is really biased towards people that have been there since the beginning. With jingles that seem to be from earlier games to the 8bit sound when you change areas... so maybe it's just a callback to earler DQ games.

Comment: Ok I checked, you are right. Loading to last save file/last location cuts half your current gold. BUT loading to last auto save brings you back to the autosave with the gold you had then.